# Google Cloud Platform Kubernetes-engine, updating a service while keeping the external IP address

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a question. I’m deploying an API with kubernetes-engine to cloud-endpoint. My problem is, every time I create the deployment and service I’m getting a new external API address.

At the moment I have to the delete the service and then create it again. With

```
kubectl delete -f deployment.yaml
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
```

Is there a different solution so I can keep my external IP address? I have this API behind my own domain and don’t want to update the DNS everytime I deploy a new version of it.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's as easy as

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
```

you can also use `kubectl apply` instead of `kubectl create`

Comment: just to elaborate, using kubectl apply -f will apply the new yaml file without deleting and recreating the resource, it will essentially update it. This means you will not lose your IP